How to Obfuscate Code in a Closed-Source SDK While Keeping Compose Function Parameters Intact?
I am developing a closed-source Android SDK where I need to obfuscate the implementation code to protect it from being reverse-engineered. However, I also need to expose certain functions to developers integrating this SDK.
One of the functions I want to expose is a Jetpack Compose function. When I enable obfuscation (minifyEnabled = true), the Compose function:
Loses its parameter names — This makes it difficult for developers to understand the function signature.
Generates additional parameters (e.g., Composer var4, int var5, int var6) which are not present in the original function definition — leading to ambiguity and confusion for developers using the SDK.
Example Code:
Expected Function Signature:
@Composable
fun BannerCarouselWithWebView(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    showWidgetTitle: Boolean = true,
    showWebViewBackButton: Boolean = true,
    configMap: Map<String, String>,
)

Actual Output After Obfuscation:
BannerCarouselWithWebView(
    Modifier var0, boolean var1, boolean var2, Map<String, String> var3, Composer var4, int var5, int var6
)

What I Need:

Keep the parameter names intact for the Compose function.
Avoid adding extra parameters like Composer and int values during
obfuscation.
Obfuscate the rest of the SDK code while preserving this specific
Compose function as-is.

What I’ve Tried:

Added ProGuard rules to exclude the Compose function, but this led to
incomplete obfuscation or runtime errors.
Used @Keep annotation on the Compose function, which prevented
obfuscation entirely but didn’t resolve the parameter transformation
issue.
Experimented with R8 rules to customize behavior, but
Compose-specific changes still persisted.

Question:

How can I configure ProGuard or R8 rules to preserve the Compose
function signature without transforming parameters while obfuscating
the rest of the SDK?
Is there a Compose-specific rule or compiler   option that prevents
these extra parameters from being added?
Are there any best practices for exposing Compose functions in
closed-source SDKs while maintaining clear API definitions?

Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated!
